# Entity Framework Core Calibre

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, .net-core

I am writing an EF core wrapper for the Calibre database. I have configured the `BookTagLink` table as follows

```
builder.HasKey(x => new {x.TagId, x.BookId });

builder.Property(b => b.BookId)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("book")
            .IsRequired();

builder.Property(b => b.TagId)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("tag")
            .IsRequired();
```

However `var book = tag.BookTagLinks.Select(b => b.Book);` errors out with:

> Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source

I think the problem is that there is an `Id` (`bigint`) set up as the primary key on the `BookTagLinks` table and when I use the book and tag ids it does not connect the dots and can't find the source.

How do one sets up a many to many relationship when there is a simple key instead of a foreign key in the database?

Comment: I assume that `tag.BookTagLinks` is null here? That's where the error omes from. Can you show your entity classes?

Comment: Yup. declared the navigation property as interface but never instantiated an hashset for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I brainfarted. I declared BookTagLinks as an ICollection but forgot to instantiate it in the constructor.
Additionally I found out that you have to specify the relationships.
I modified my class as follow 
`public override void Map(EntityTypeBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.ToTable("books_tags_link");

```
        base.Map(builder);

        builder.HasKey(x => new {x.TagId, x.BookId });

        builder.HasOne(bt => bt.Book)
            .WithMany(b => b.BookTagLinks)
            .HasForeignKey(bt => bt.BookId);

        builder.HasOne(bt => bt.Tag)
            .WithMany(t => t.BookTagLinks)
            .HasForeignKey(bt => bt.TagId);

        builder.Property(b => b.BookId)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("book")
            .IsRequired();

        builder.Property(b => b.TagId)
            .ForSqliteHasColumnName("tag")
            .IsRequired();

    }`
```

And now everything works...